# Selecting second entry in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I need to select the second entry in the User model.

`User.second` does not work, nor does `User.2` or `User.two`.

I'm trying to set `u` to the second User entry (`u = User.2`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

```
User.all.second
User.offset(1).first

# Assuming you are using incremental keys and have users with ID's 1 and 2:
User.find(2)
```